# VueJS components with IDS

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to VueJS and I am trying to wrap my mind around a concept.

I have a sidebar that shows different classrooms that are in my database. Each Classroom can have one or more notebooks attached to it.

What I want to happen is that when you click on a classroom, it loads up the classroom component and shows a list of all the notebooks that are linked to that classroom.

I am really not sure how to go about this. I first thought about treating this like a route, where I could add a slug to the classroom controller such as

```
Route::get('/notebook/{id}', 'NotebookController@show');
```

But this wouldn't make sense because this would only retrieve the notebook for this specific classroom but it wouldn't show it in the component. And also there is no way for me to necessarily get the classroom from the side bar.

Here is what I have to load all the classrooms in the side bar:

```
<li class="nav-itme" v-for="classroom in ClassRooms" v-bind:classroom="classroom" v-bind:key="classroom.id">
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'classroom' }" class="nav-link">{{classroom.name}}</router-link>
</li>
```

I feel like what I am asking for is very beginner level and if someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is this for a multipage app or a SPA?

Comment: Single page app